# Depedency injection and Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

What's the point of using Dagger2 and Kotlin ?

Dagger2 docs says:

"Constructor injection is preferred whenever possible because javac will ensure that no field is referenced before it has been set, which helps avoid NullPointerExceptions."

The main reason why Kotlin exists is to provide null safety.

So is it worth to use Dagger2 with Kotlin ?

Comment: you've put very little effort into your research

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This quote (which I don't directly see in the docs, but never mind) says that one way of using Dagger (constructor injection) is more null-safe than another (method injection).

It doesn't say anything about using Dagger to provide null safety compared to not using Dagger.

If you use Dagger's constructor injection with Kotlin, your properties will be normal non-nullable ones; if you use method injection, you'll need to make them nullable or use `lateinit`. So constructor injection still provides more null-safety than method injection when used with Kotlin.